# PHP Timeout to Logs Table

Tags: php, curl

I have it set up in my PHP.ini file to timeout after 30 seconds. I want to keep this setting. I have a script that connects to an API and every once in a while (like 1 in 10 times), it can't connect so it spends the entire 30 seconds. This connection is via curl.

I have a logs table in my database and I would like before the timeout occurs to insert a new item. Is this possible via PHP to insert a row on timeout for only this particular script?

I have done my own research and can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to execute something on script shutdown. It will even be called on script timeout.

**edit:**

Alternatively you can use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to set the max execution time for your `curl` execution to something below 30s and then look at the returned value to see if max execution was reached and then log to the database.